# configure security.yml firewall with 2 type of login

Tags: symfony

My security.yml code throws me route error sometimes. I think my code is wrong. This is my code for security.yml so far

```
firewalls:
    main_login:
        pattern:    ^/account
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path:  /account/login
            check_path:  /account/login_check
        logout:
            path:   /account/logout
            target: /

    oauth_login:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: ~
        oauth:
            resource_owners:
                facebook:      /connect/login_facebook
            login_path:        /connect/login
            use_forward:       false
            failure_path:      /connect/login
            default_target_path: /connectfb

    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern:  ^/connect/login$
        security: false

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/account, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

How is the best way to configure my security.yml
I need main_login as my primary login option and oauth_login as secondary
I tried to use `pattern: ^/` on main_login and  `pattern: ^/connect` on oauth_login. but it didn't work. As in my current code give this error `No route found for "GET /account/login" (from "http://localhost/app_dev.php/login")` if I put wrong username or password for login.

and i want login and logout path for main_login to be just `/login` and `/logout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
login:
    pattern:  ^/connect/login$
    security: false
```

I had a similar problem using FOSUSerBundle, SonataAdminBundle and HWIOAuthBundle

I found the answer in the [SonataUserBundle installation step](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/master/doc/reference/installation.html#integrating-the-bundle-into-the-sonata-admin-bundle)

I edited to match your routes

```
firewalls:
    # Disabling the security for the web debug toolbar, the profiler and Assetic.
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    # -> custom firewall for the admin area of the URL
    main_login:
        pattern:        /account(.*)
        context:        user
        form_login:
            provider:       fos_userbundle
            login_path:     /account/login
            use_forward:    false
            check_path:     /account/login_check
            failure_path:   null
        logout:
            path:           /account/logout
        anonymous:  true
    # -> end custom configuration

    # default login area for standard users

    # This firewall is used to handle the public login area
    # This part is handled by the FOS User Bundle

    # secured_area is user for hwioauthbundle
    oauth_login: 
        pattern:            .*
        context:            user
        remember_me:
            key:            %secret%
            lifetime:       30 # 365 days in seconds
            path:           /
            always_remember_me: true
            remember_me_parameter: _remember_me
        form_login:
            provider:       fos_userbundle
            login_path:     /connect/login
            use_forward:    false
            check_path:     /login_check
            failure_path:   null
        logout:
            path:           /connect/logout
        oauth:
            remember_me:    true

            # https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/internals/response_object_and_paths.md
            resource_owners:
                facebook:       "/connect/login_facebook"
            login_path:        /connect/login
            use_forward:       false
            failure_path:      /connect/login

            oauth_user_provider:
                service:  my_user_provider
        anonymous:          true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/account, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: thank you very much. and yes those login is the root of my problem :)